How to create a proforma invoice with QuestPDF
I am working on a Order Management Application with Blazor Server. I need to create a PDF proforma invoice so I decided to use QuestPDF. I installed 2024.7.3 version on my project. I am trying to design an invoice like this;

Here is what I could do so far;
ProformaInvoiceDocument.cs
using QuestPDF.Fluent;
using QuestPDF.Helpers;
using QuestPDF.Infrastructure;
using Image = QuestPDF.Infrastructure.Image;

namespace IMS.CoreBusiness;

public class ProformaInvoiceDocument : IDocument
{
    public static Image LogoImage { get; } = Image.FromFile("wwwroot/css/images/logo.png");

    public ProformaInvoice Model { get; }

    public ProformaInvoiceDocument(ProformaInvoice model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public DocumentMetadata GetMetadata() => DocumentMetadata.Default;
    public DocumentSettings GetSettings() => DocumentSettings.Default;

    public void Compose(IDocumentContainer container)
    {
        container.Page(page =>
        {
            page.Size(PageSizes.A4);
            page.Margin(1, Unit.Centimetre);
            page.PageColor(Colors.White);
            page.DefaultTextStyle(x => x.FontSize(12));

            page.Header().Component(new InvoiceHeader(LogoImage));
            page.Content().Component(new InvoiceContent(Model.InvoiceNumber, Model.InvoiceDate, Model.CustomerName, Model.CustomerAddress, Model.Items, Model.Subtotal, Model.VAT, Model.Total, Model.BankDetails, Model.Notes));
            //page.Footer().Component(new InvoiceFooter(Model.FooterText));
        });
    }
}

Here is header:
public class InvoiceHeader : IComponent
{

    private readonly Image LogoImage;

    public InvoiceHeader(Image logoImage)
    {
        LogoImage = logoImage;
    }

    public void Compose(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Row(row =>
        {

            row.ConstantItem(170).Image(LogoImage);


        });
    }
}

Here is the content:
public class InvoiceContent : IComponent
{
    private readonly List<InvoiceItem> Items;
    private readonly decimal Subtotal;
    private readonly decimal VAT;
    private readonly decimal Total;
    private readonly string BankDetails;
    private readonly string Notes;
    private readonly string InvoiceNumber;
    private readonly DateTime InvoiceDate;
    private readonly string CustomerName;
    private readonly string CustomerAddress;

    public InvoiceContent(string invoiceNumber, DateTime invoiceDate, string customerName, string customerAddress, List<InvoiceItem> items, decimal subtotal, decimal vat, decimal total, string bankDetails, string notes)
    {
        InvoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
        InvoiceDate = invoiceDate;
        CustomerName = customerName;
        CustomerAddress = customerAddress;
        Items = items;
        Subtotal = subtotal;
        VAT = vat;
        Total = total;
        BankDetails = bankDetails;
        Notes = notes;
    }

    public void Compose(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Row(row =>
        {
            row.Spacing(30);


            row.RelativeItem().Column(column =>
            {
                
                column.Item().Text(text =>
                {
                    text.Span("Invoice No: ").SemiBold();
                    text.Span($"{InvoiceNumber}");
                });

                column.Item().Text(text =>
                {
                    text.Span("Date: ").SemiBold();
                    text.Span($"{InvoiceDate:dd/MM/yyyy}");
                });

                column.Item().Text(text =>
                {
                    text.Span("Customer: ").SemiBold();
                    text.Span($"{CustomerName}");
                });

                column.Item().Text(text =>
                {
                    text.Span("Address: ").SemiBold();
                    text.Span($"{CustomerAddress}");
                });
            });
        });

        container.Column(column =>
        {
            column.Spacing(10);

            // Items Table Section
            column.Item().Table(table =>
            {
                table.ColumnsDefinition(columns =>
                {
                    columns.RelativeColumn();
                    columns.RelativeColumn();
                    columns.RelativeColumn();
                    columns.RelativeColumn();
                });

                table.Header(header =>
                {
                    header.Cell().Text("Ürün Kodu").Bold();
                    header.Cell().Text("Ürün Açıklaması").Bold();
                    header.Cell().Text("Üretici Kodu").Bold();
                    header.Cell().Text("Üretici Adı").Bold();
                });

                // Add rows for items
                foreach (var item in Items)
                {
                    TextExtensions.Text((IContainer)table.Cell(), (string?)item.Code);
                    TextExtensions.Text((IContainer)table.Cell(), (string?)item.Description);
                    TextExtensions.Text((IContainer)table.Cell(), (string?)item.ManufacturerCode);
                    TextExtensions.Text((IContainer)table.Cell(), (string?)item.ManufacturerName);
                }
            });

            // Totals Section
            column.Item().PaddingVertical(10).Row(row =>
            {
                row.RelativeItem().Text($"Subtotal: {Subtotal:C2}").FontSize(12);
                row.RelativeItem().Text($"VAT: {VAT:C2}").FontSize(12);
                row.RelativeItem().Text($"Total: {Total:C2}").FontSize(14).Bold();
            });

            // Bank Details Section
            column.Item().Text("Bank Details:").Bold();
            column.Item().Text(BankDetails);

            // Notes Section
            column.Item().Text("Notes/Terms:").Bold();
            column.Item().Text(Notes);
        });
    }
}


How I am calling it
void Submit(Order arg)
{
    var invoiceDocument = new IMS.CoreBusiness.ProformaInvoice
    {
        InvoiceNumber = "123456",
        InvoiceDate = DateTime.Now,
        CustomerName = "Example Customer",
        CustomerAddress = "123 Example Street",
        Items = new List<InvoiceItem>
        {
            new InvoiceItem { Code = "ABC123", Description = "Item 1", ManufacturerCode = "MAN123", ManufacturerName = "Company A", Price = 100 },
            new InvoiceItem { Code = "XYZ456", Description = "Item 2", ManufacturerCode = "MAN456", ManufacturerName = "Company B", Price = 200 }
        },
        Subtotal = 300,
        VAT = 54,
        Total = 354,
        BankDetails = "Your Bank Details Here",
        Notes = "Terms and conditions apply.",
        FooterText = "Company Address, Contact Info, etc."
    };

    var document = new ProformaInvoiceDocument(invoiceDocument);
    document.GeneratePdfAndShow();
    // document.ShowInPreviewer();
}

I am getting this error if I add this portion to the conten
container.Row(row =>
{
    row.Spacing(30);


    row.RelativeItem().Column(column =>
    {
        //column
        //    .Item().Text("IME General Components")
        //    .FontSize(20).Bold().FontColor(Colors.Blue.Medium);

        column.Item().Text(text =>
        {
            text.Span("Invoice No: ").SemiBold();
            text.Span($"{InvoiceNumber}");
        });

        column.Item().Text(text =>
        {
            text.Span("Date: ").SemiBold();
            text.Span($"{InvoiceDate:dd/MM/yyyy}");
        });

        column.Item().Text(text =>
        {
            text.Span("Customer: ").SemiBold();
            text.Span($"{CustomerName}");
        });

        column.Item().Text(text =>
        {
            text.Span("Address: ").SemiBold();
            text.Span($"{CustomerAddress}");
        });
    });
});

QuestPDF.Drawing.Exceptions.DocumentComposeException: You should not assign multiple child elements to a single-child container. This may happen when a container variable is used outside of its scope/closure OR the container is used in multiple fluent API chains OR the container is used incorrectly in a loop. This exception is thrown to help you detect that some part of the code is overriding fragments of the document layout with a new content - essentially destroying existing content.
Someone can help me to design a template like the one in my sample picture?
Thank you.

I don't understand what you mean @Fildor. Can you please elaborate?

Nevermind, I was mistaken. Still trying to figure it out.

I need to design a template like the one in the post. Hope someone can help me.

Look into the stacktrace and find the line that throws the exception. I can't see which one that should be just from eyeballing it.

Can you reproduce that in a simpler example? => [mre] ?

I solved my issue, generated what I wanted, and posted it as an answer. @Fildor

Here is how I solved my issue and generated the design I wanted.

Here is the structure:
public class ProformaInvoiceDocument : IDocument
{
    public static Image LogoImage { get; } = Image.FromFile("wwwroot/css/images/logo.png");

    public ProformaInvoice Model { get; }

    public ProformaInvoiceDocument(ProformaInvoice model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public DocumentMetadata GetMetadata() => DocumentMetadata.Default;
    public DocumentSettings GetSettings() => DocumentSettings.Default;

    public void Compose(IDocumentContainer container)
    {
        container.Page(page =>
        {
            page.Size(PageSizes.A4.Landscape());
            page.Margin(1, Unit.Centimetre);
            page.PageColor(Colors.White);
            page.DefaultTextStyle(x => x.FontSize(9));

            page.Header().Component(new InvoiceHeader(LogoImage));
            page.Content().Component(new InvoiceContent(Model));
            page.Footer().Component(new InvoiceFooter(Model));
        });
    }
}

public class InvoiceHeader : IComponent
{

    private readonly Image LogoImage;

    public InvoiceHeader(Image logoImage)
    {
        LogoImage = logoImage;
    }

    public void Compose(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Row(row =>
        {

            row.ConstantItem(170).Image(LogoImage);


        });
    }
}

public class InvoiceContent : IComponent
    {
        private readonly ProformaInvoice Model;


        public InvoiceContent(ProformaInvoice model)
        {
            Model = model;

        }

        public void Compose(IContainer container)
        {
            container.PaddingVertical(40).Column(column =>
            {
                // Add a line 
                column.Item().PaddingTop(5).PaddingBottom(25).LineHorizontal(1).LineColor(Colors.Grey.Medium);

                //column.Spacing(5);

                column.Item().Row(row =>
                {
                    row.RelativeItem().Component(new InvoiceContentRow31(Model));
                    row.ConstantItem(1);
                    row.RelativeItem().Component(new InvoiceContentRow32(Model));
                    row.ConstantItem(1);
                    row.RelativeItem().Component(new InvoiceContentRow33(Model));
                });

                column.Item().PaddingTop(25).Element(ComposeRow4);

                column.Item().Component(new TotalsSection(Model));

                column.Item().PaddingTop(20).Component(new NotesSection(Model.Notes));



            });


            void ComposeRow4(IContainer container)
            {

                container.Table(table =>
                    {
                        // step 1
                        table.ColumnsDefinition(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.ConstantColumn(25);
                            columns.RelativeColumn(3);
                            columns.RelativeColumn();
                            columns.RelativeColumn();
                            columns.RelativeColumn();
                        });

                        // step 2
                        table.Header(header =>
                        {
                            header.Cell().Element(CellStyle).Text("#");
                            header.Cell().Element(CellStyle).Text("Product");
                            header.Cell().Element(CellStyle).AlignRight().Text("Unit price");
                            header.Cell().Element(CellStyle).AlignRight().Text("Quantity");
                            header.Cell().Element(CellStyle).AlignRight().Text("Total");

                            static IContainer CellStyle(IContainer container)
                            {
                                return container.DefaultTextStyle(x => x.SemiBold()).PaddingVertical(5).BorderBottom(1).BorderColor(Colors.Black);
                            }
                        });

                        // step 3
                        foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                        {
                            table.Cell().Element(CellStyle).Text(Model.Items.IndexOf(item) + 1);
                            table.Cell().Element(CellStyle).Text(item.Description);
                            table.Cell().Element(CellStyle).AlignRight().Text($"{item.Price}$");
                            table.Cell().Element(CellStyle).AlignRight().Text(item.ManufacturerCode);
                            table.Cell().Element(CellStyle).AlignRight().Text($"{item.Price}$");

                            static IContainer CellStyle(IContainer container)
                            {
                                return container.BorderBottom(1).BorderColor(Colors.Grey.Lighten2).PaddingVertical(5);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }


        }
    }
public class InvoiceFooter : IComponent
{
    private readonly ProformaInvoice Model;

    public InvoiceFooter(ProformaInvoice model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public void Compose(IContainer container)
    {
        container.ShowEntire().Column(column =>
        {
            // Add a line
            column.Item().PaddingTop(10).LineHorizontal(1).LineColor(Colors.Grey.Medium);

            column.Spacing(2);

            column.Item().AlignCenter().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span($"{Model.CustomerAddress}");
            });

            column.Item().AlignCenter().Text(text =>
            {
                text.Span($"{Model.Telephone}");
            });


        });
    }
}


Can you add what ecxactly caused that exception and how your solution was able to fix that?

I was trying to add more than one container in the content section. I added different components instead.
